# Connection of 2 external monitors on Dell6430 laptop with docking station

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I'm in need of some outside-of-the-box thinking. At my work, I've tried every which way to connect my 2 external Dell (work) monitors to my work laptop (Dell6430). I've tried different cables and different settings in screen resolution to no avail. It seems as if it will only display on 2 screens at a time, never all 3. I've even tried "Fn" + F8 button.... nada. Currently, both monitors are plugged into the docking station, one VGA cable, the second with a DVI cable with a DP/N display DVI adapter cable that came with; I've tried with and without the adaptor cable— no luck). 
Thus, I'm using my 2 monitors and my laptop screen is blank (dark/won't display). 
OS: Windows 7 Enterprise, with Service Pack 1
Please help me fix this so that I may utilize all 3 screens. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Many graphics cards will not support more than 2 active displays over HDMI or DVI. For more than 2 displays your machine needs to have a DisplayPort output and you need an **active** DisplayPort adaptor or DisplayPort monitor.

Comment: Thank you.... I do have the display port adaptor connected currently. Maybe it is the design, then. Darn. Such a waste to have a monitor right in front of me that I can't use. :/  Thank you anyway.

Comment: You have an adaptor, but are you certain it is an active adaptor rather than a passive one? DisplayPort can fall back to a HDMI mode, but with an active adaptor it might actually work properly.

Comment: Hmmmmm..... another piece to the puzzle. How can I determine whether it's active or passive? Kinda seems asinine to create a "passive" piece of technology, lol

Comment: By passive it means it is simply a wire adaptor, and expects the computer to fall back to a mode the monitor supports. An active adaptor takes in *native* DisplayPort and has actual electronics to convert to the required output. Rule of thumb: if it cost less than $10 it's probably a passive adaptor. Google whatever part number you can find on it, most active adaptors mention it very specifically: http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&sku=a7199439

Comment: You rock. This is the first I've heard of this to be honest. Well, that's how you learn. I will do so. Hopefully, I can get my own ACTIVE adaptor..... ;)

Comment: I'm not 100% certain it will work, but everything I've seen says it *should* so I'm like 99%. Almost all graphics cards have a requirement that for >2 monitors at least one of them needs to be a proper DisplayPort monitor (or via an active adaptor). Hopefully it will work.

Comment: It's indeed passive! The model number was indicated as such in an article.  I'll have to seek out an active one! Thank you again! 

Comment: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3515/t/19458571

Comment: The active cable didn't make a difference.... researching what to do.....

Comment: That active cable didn't work. Might it be the video card?

Comment: It may well be.  Do you have the Intel graphics version or the Nvidia graphics? There are suggestions that it does work when docked: http://www.jdhodges.com/blog/dell-e6430-triple-display-output/ but I'm not convinced considering your experience...

Comment: http://uncorkingtech.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/triple-monitors-on-dell-latitude-e6520.html suggests that the Intel version cannot support 3 displays while the Nvidia variant can.

Comment: I bet mine has the Intel. Ugh. How stupid. I have an extra screen that could be put to use, but can't. Thx so much for all your input. I appreciate it. 